# best way to store coordinates in arrays and comparing them in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, double

Asking for java help

I am 1.5 weeks into programming so try and make an answer easy for an idoit. And this answer is probably out there and I am probably to dumb to realize I read it already.

So I have a bunch of object instances and I want to add Instance.position which is

```
double[] position = (x,y);
```

to  some sort of array/list/stack so I can the check to see if a different object Instance.position is the same as one I set to the array/stack/list.
This is what i have:

`public ArrayList<double[]> objPositions = new ArrayList<double[]>();`

`public boolean isThereAObj(double[] userPosition){`
`if (objPositions.contains(userPosition));`
`return true;`
`}`
this does not work.. (i think)

where the array list has already been defined earlier 
and ideally my array list could be of objects and i could check the objects element position with my comparing objects position.

So basically I want to have a list with all instances of all objects I create in my program and then I want to be able to compare one or more of their elements to a different object (not on the list)

Comment: Don't get panic. Someone surely help you out. Show us your code.

Comment: So you have given set of 2D points (as `double[]` arrays) and want to check whether a particular (new) point is already contained in this set?

Comment: <code>public ArrayList<double[]> wallPositions = new ArrayList<double[]>();

public boolean isThereAWall(double[] userPosition){
if (wallPositions.contains(userPosition));
return true;
}</code>

Comment: yes marco thats what I want to do

Comment: Just pot the quotes around your code, don't surround it with 'code': `public ArrayList<double[]> wallPositions = new ArrayList<double[]>(); public boolean isThereAWall(double[] userPosition){ if (wallPositions.contains(userPosition)); return true; }` and edit your initial post to make the code readable, plese.

Comment: This is what i have:

`public ArrayList<double[]> objPositions = new ArrayList<double[]>();`

`public boolean isThereAWall(double[] userPosition){`
`if (objPositions.contains(userPosition));`
`return true;`
`}`
this does not work.. (i think)

where the array list has already been defined earlier 
and ideally my array list could be of objects and i could check the objects element position with my comparing objects positon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two arrays of integers order-insensitively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665593/how-to-compare-two-arrays-of-integers-order-insensitively)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues here. First, it is not very elegant to describe a 2D point as a 2-element `double[]` array. Instead, you should consider using `java.awt.geom.Point2D` objects:

```
Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(x,y);
```

This makes the implementation of the method that you are looking for much easier:

```
private final List<Point2D> wallPositions = new ArrayList<Point2D>(); 
public boolean isThereAWall(Point2D userPosition) { 
    return wallPositions.contains(userPosition); 
}
```

The problem with your current attempt is that `double[]` arrays do not know the concept of "equality" that you are looking for. (More formally: There is no appropriate implementation of the `Object#equals(Object)` method for them)

However, if you want to stick to your double arrays (although I do **not** recommend this), you could do something like

```
private final List<double[]> wallPositions = new ArrayList<double[]>(); 

public boolean isThereAWall(double[] userPosition) { 
    for (double entry[] : wallPositions) {
        if (Arrays.equal(entry, userPosition)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But there may (in **both** cases) be another caveat, namely the limited precision of `double` values. There are *very* few cases where it is appropriate to compare `double` values for identity (with `==`). But whether this really is a problem here depends on your application case.

Comment: so what if i want to add a number to the x or y value in "Point2d p"... say i want to move the object from 1.0,1.0 to 2.0, 1.0?

Comment: @user3337754 `p.setLocation(p.getX()+1, p.getY());`

Comment: it is "java.awt.geom.Point2D"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Point2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html), which is exactly meant to store 2 `double`s in a `Point` object. You can keep multiple points in an `ArrayList`, as you are now. To check whether a point already exists, you'd just loop through it and call `.equals(newPoint)` to compare the points. However, as `double` precision points might not ever equal each other, you probably want to check whether two points are within a certain small distance from each other (again, with `equals()` for example).

Comment: OK, that's the short version of mine ;-) Just an aside: Point2D already overrides `equals`, so you can just call `list.contains(point)` without a manual loop. However, the precision may still be an issue, and for some "epsilon-comparison", one would have to do the manual loop again anyhow

Comment: can i compare with an Instance.Element if i had just an array of Instances?